# R: Import scripts from internet site

Tags: r, import

I wondering if its possible import or read scripts from a internet site, I would like import scripts from:
http://archived.stat.ufl.edu/casella/StatDesign/WebRPrograms/

I did try with

```
setwd("http://archived.stat.ufl.edu/casella/StatDesign/WebRPrograms/")
```

or

```
script=source("http://archived.stat.ufl.edu/casella/StatDesign/WebRPrograms/FishTank.R")
```

But gave me an error.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `source("http://archived.stat.ufl.edu/casella/StatDesign/WebRPrograms/FishTank.R")` works just fine. The error is from the content of that script (in particular, you probably don't have a file `c:/WorkHome07/StatDesign/DataSets/FishTank.txt` on your system).

Comment: Its possible edit the script to dont get the error because dont have this file: c:/WorkHome07/StatDesign/DataSets/FishTank.txt)

Comment: See the answer by @JBGruber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These look like files that you need to use interactively (e.g., open them in RStudio) as they contain absolute links to files (e.g. `read.table("c:/Work08/StatDesignSC08/Data/Alfalfa.txt",sep = "",header=T)`). I would suggest you download them and then open them. For example using these commands:

```
source_file <- "http://archived.stat.ufl.edu/casella/StatDesign/WebRPrograms/Alfalfa.R"

download.file(url = source_file, destfile = basename(source_file))

file.edit(basename(source_file))
```

And then edit the paths you need. Otherwise you will constatntly run into `cannot open file` errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `source_url` from `devtools` package.

```
library(devtools)  
source_url("http://archived.stat.ufl.edu/casella/StatDesign/WebRPrograms/FishTank.R")
```

Please note that on windows this should also work:

```
source("http://archived.stat.ufl.edu/casella/StatDesign/WebRPrograms/FishTank.R")
```